# How do I create a pie chart from VML shapes?

Tags: highcharts, vml

I realize that VML is deprecated as of IE9, but I need compatibility with older versions. I have been looking at [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), and how they make their otherwise SVG-based charts work with IE 6.0+, and the answer is VML.

As I have been able to render some examples in IE8 with the help of Highcharts, I have also been able to extract some source code examples to play with. [This specific chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-semi-circle) is the one I am trying to understand and recreate. I do not care about animations, tool tip texts or highlighting. I basically want to understand how i can draw polygons that include curves, and in this case, as a part of a half donut-shaped pie chart.

The code below represents an example that has three slices of a pie chart, inside a frame-shape. I have been playing around with the numbers, but I cannot figure out exactly what the following values represent:

```
path = " 
wr1120,933,4670,4483,0,2600,1170,2248 
at2058,1870,3733,3545,2081,2510,500,2510 x e"
```

They obviously represent some kind of coordinates, angles or distances, but after both playing around with them, and searching for documentation, I couldn't come to an understanding.

But, this I found out (values named wr1-8 and at1-8):

-wr seems to represent the outer circle, while at represents the inner cut-out (hole in the donut)

- values wr1-2 and at1-2 seems to represent some kind of mask of the total circle.
- values wr3-4 and at3-4 seems to represent some kind of arch rotation, or something else arch related. all numbers 1-4 are equal in all slices
- values 5-6 and 7-8 on both at and wr seems to represent continual coordinates, where the next slice starts where the previous stopped. However, I cannot find a pattern when I change the numbers. I cannot find the system.

So what does these values actually represent? Or better yet, where can i find documentation that explains this?

Below is the complete code of a three sliced half donut pie chart example:

```
<!doctype html public '-//W3C//DTD html 4.0 Transitional//EN'><%@ Language=VBScript%>
<html xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml'>
<STYLE>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}}</STYLE>



<shape style="POSITION: absolute; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; WIDTH: 1px; 
DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1px; VISIBILITY: visible; 
MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#VML); 
LEFT: 0px" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" stroke-linejoin="round" 
coordsize = "10,10" filled = "t" fillcolor = "#00FF00" stroked = "t" 
strokecolor = "white" strokeweight = ".75pt" 
path = " wr1120,933,4670,4483,0,2600,1170,2248 
at2058,1870,3733,3545,2081,2510,500,2510 x e"><fill style="DISPLAY: 
inline-block; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#VML)" 
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" type = "solid" opacity = "1">
</fill></shape>

<shape style="POSITION: absolute; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; WIDTH: 1px; 
DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1px; VISIBILITY: visible; 
MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#VML); 
LEFT: 0px" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" stroke-linejoin="round" 
coordsize = "10,10" filled = "t" fillcolor = "#dddf00" stroked = "t" 
strokecolor = "white" strokeweight = ".75pt" path = " 
wr1120,933,4670,4483,1170,2248,2509,975 
at2058,1870,3733,3545,2713,1890,2081,2510 x e">
<fill style="DISPLAY: inline-block; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#VML)" 
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" type = "solid" opacity = "0.5">
</fill></shape>

<shape style="POSITION: absolute; MARGIN-TOP: 0px; WIDTH: 1px; 
DISPLAY: inline-block; HEIGHT: 1px; VISIBILITY: visible; 
MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px; BEHAVIOR: url(#default#VML); 
LEFT: 0px" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" stroke-linejoin="round" 
coordsize = "10,10" filled = "t" fillcolor = "#ed561b" stroked = "t" 
strokecolor = "white" strokeweight = ".75pt" 
path = " wr1120,933,4670,4483,2509,975,2579,961 
at2058,1870,3733,3545,2746,1883,2713,1890 x e">
</shape>
```

Comment: So you need to create pie chart in native VML without any additoanl plugin like highcahrts?

Comment: Yeah, the visual result is not really my goal here. I am curious of how it works. Need might not be the word, as much as "want" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- wr means "clockwise arch"
- at means "arch to"

The 8 numbers represent 4 (x, y)-paired coordinates in both cases. The two first pairs represent the upper left, and lower right coordinates of the bounding box of an elipse. To put it simple, it is the coordinates on the canvas where you press the mouse, and where you release the mouse while drawing a circle shape in MS Paint.

The two last pairs represent coordinates, which gives vectors from the center of the circle, to the given coordinate. The angles produced will be the starting and ending angle of the given slice.

the angles only decides the cutting point inbetween the bounding circle, and the vector. In other words, the angles only gives a point, not a side. Both the inner and the outer circle needs matching vector angles, to give a nice presentation, where the lines that seperates the sides of the donut slices, would all cross in the center of the donut hole.

For more info about all possible commands for the path, see:

http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/NOTE-VML-19980513#_Toc416858391

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating in SVG first, then converting to VML, if that's possible for you.  I recently figured out how to do so.

Essentially it involves using this stylesheet: http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/pollett/masters/Semesters/Fall03/JulieNabong/translator.xsl

You also need Notepad++ and its XML Tools plugin.

```
1 - Open up the SVG file in Notepad++
2 - Go to Plugins --> XML Tools --> XSL Transformations
3 - Select the translator.xsl stylesheet
4 - Click on "Transform"
```

Here's the thesis' demo page:
http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/pollett/masters/Semesters/Fall03/JulieNabong/index.shtml?display.html